# Will libraries built under Gentoo with Interix work outside Gentoo?

Tags: c++, dependencies, runtime, gentoo, interix

The Gentoo Linux distribution has a version that works on Interix x86 Windows.  If I build C++ libraries using gcc, will these libraries work with an executable not built inside Gentoo, but only inside Interix?  Do I create a dependency on any Gentoo install for runtime or is Interix the only dependency of such libraries and thus its use at compile time does not create a runtime dependency?

Comment: They should work, but you might want to take a look at the Gentoo Prefix project. Cygwin is the official way to build and run Gentoo on Windows.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix#Special_notes_for_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: I agree that it "should work" without issue.  I have never personally used Interix, however, software built on Gentoo with GCC / MinGW have historically worked for me on other Linux / Windows systems.